# Why SpringBoot App finish with exit code 0 when running on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I've built this [simple application](https://github.com/Rmulorm/spring-modules-intellij-problem) with Java 11 and Spring Boot

I've split my application into two modules:

- Application -> Spring Boot application and a Simple Controller
- Service -> A simple service that just returns hello world.

This was supposed to be a simple application that simply returns "Hello World" to an HTTP GET on `localhost:8080/`

When I start the application from the terminal using `mvn spring-boot:run -pl application` the application starts normally and I can perform the HTTP GET, but if I start the application with IntelliJ, using the default config for Spring Boot Application, the process finishes with exit code 0 and nothing happens. The complete error log is [here](https://github.com/Rmulorm/spring-modules-intellij-problem/blob/main/application/IntelliJ-error-log.txt).

This is a demo project that I created just to try to replica this problem that I'm facing in a real application I'm building. With this error, I'm finding a way to debug the application.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Here are my Java and Maven Versions:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-sapmachine)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-sapmachine, mixed mode)
```

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: REDACTED
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: SAP SE, runtime: REDACTED
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: `REDACTED`? Seriously?

Comment: I've thought it would be funny...
I just didn't want to expose that information because I didn't think it would be useful

Comment: If I run it as it is I get "module application does not open com.example.application to unnamed module @4066c471" And if I remove the modul-info files it runs without a problem